# Navigation Bar Not Showing after Adding NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift

I have an existing `UITableViewController` that I've embedded in a `NavigationController`. However, the Navigation Bar is not showing when I present the view.

Presenting the `TableViewController` (its Storyboard id is: `SelectServicesController`) :

```
if let selectServicesController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SelectServicesController") as? UITableViewController {
    self.navigationController?.presentViewController(selectServicesController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image]

This is what it looks like when I build (nav bar does not show):

[image]

Comment: Do you have other navigation controllers in your project?

Comment: @DanielLeonard Yes I do. This is a separate Navigation Controller.

Comment: Ya but it can effect it because it is a parent navigation controller. Also do you have constraints on your table view to the top of its super view.

Comment: @DanielLeonard So should I use the same parent navigation controller? The problem is I want to present this tableview controller modally. And no I did not set constraints because it is a tableview controller and I cannot set the constraints for the tableview.

Comment: Ya it just seemed strange you text was on top of the carrier information of the view.

Comment: Its not a problem that you have a parent Navigation controller its just going to inherit all the same properties so if you have hidden it the new one will be hidden as well.

Answer (score 5):

So I just did this and at fist could not get it to show up at all. Then Figured it out, You just need to select the navigation controller and set it to be the ✅`is initial View Controller`

This is what your storyboard should look like
[image: NavigationController setup]

Then to make everything show up I added this to my `viewDidLoad` of the view the Navigation controller is presenting. This step is more optional.

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()]
    navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = false
```

And this is what it looks like

[image: NavContorllerInAction]

mmmm Red on black  Hope that helps you.

Comment: I tried this, but I get an error that navigationController returns nil.

Comment: ya so my answer will not work because it is mission completely as in there is no navigation controller at all.

Answer (score 5):

You're presenting a UITableViewController, which doesn't have a navigation controller as a parent (even though your Storyboard has it first, you're not actually using it).

You can fix this by doing something like this:

```
if let selectServicesController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SelectServicesController") as? UITableViewController {
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: selectServicesController)
    self.navigationController?.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Or by setting the navigation controller as the *initial view controller* of the storyboard and then calling it like this:

```
if let selectServicesController = self.storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController() {
    self.navigationController?.presentViewController(selectServicesController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem. I solved it by Changing the segue to the navigation controller that embeds the View Controller I want to display.
[image]

Hopefully it would work for you. 
Let me know if it is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Expense", bundle: Bundle(for: PTCAddExpenseViewController.self))


let controller =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"AddExpense") as! PTCAddExpenseViewController



let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)

self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this works for me:

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You're presenting the table view controller directly, not its navigation controller. If you mark the nav controller as the initial view controller (tick the "Is initial view controller" box in the attributes inspector), then you can instantiate and show it by:

```
if let selectServicesNavController = self.storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController() as? UINavigationController {
    // if you're pushing it onto an existing nav controller
    self.navigationController?.presentViewController(selectServicesNavController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    // if not (and this is probably the case), set the nav controller as your window's rootViewController
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow.rootViewController = selectServicesNavController
}
```

Comment: The problem is, I have another Navigation Controller.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is Xcode is ignoring the fact that your table view controller is embedded in navigation controller when presenting your table view controller with the following code:

```
if let selectServicesController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SelectServicesController") as? UITableViewController {
    self.navigationController?.presentViewController(selectServicesController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Instead, I would suggest you modify the Top Bar setting under Simulated Metrics to suit your needs or instantiate your navigation controller instead (the latter is preferred and recommended)

Comment: I tried adding opaque top bar but it still does not show anything.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, change this line

```
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(selectServicesController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to this

```
self.presentViewController(selectServicesController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I've tried adding a storyboard ID to the navigation bar and present the navigation controller instead. But the view completely ignores the call completely and does not show the navigation controller nor the tableviewcontroller.

Comment: You need to present the navigation controller from the view controller itself, not the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

I read in one of your comments you want to present the table view controller modally, with the navigation bar showing. We can do this using the Storyboard. From the view controller that should display this table view controller modally, Ctrl+Drag from the view controller to the Navigation Controller of the Table View Controller. Then, select **Present Modally**. Set an **Identifier** for the segue. Then, in your code for the view controller that is presenting the table view controller modally, call:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("YourSegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
```

Another way to do this without having to use any code is if the modal presentation is being triggered by something like a button. Then, you can Ctrl+Drag from that button to the Navigation Controller and select Present Modally.

Answer (score 0):

Or it might be this!!

I had the same problem: the navigation bar was showing on the root view in Storyboard, but when running the Simulator - there was no navigation bar at the top of the views. This solved it:

Navigation Controller > Navigation Bar > UNCHECK Translucent (it is checked by default). This did two things:

1. My Navigation Bar shows on all subsequent views.
2. The topmost subview is now at Y=0, and not Y=64.

[image]