# navigationItem.leftBarButton is not appearing (Xcode Swift 4 IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uibarbuttonitem

I have made a [UITableViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcontroller)(iOS controller for table views) and attempted to put a logout button in the top left corner of the screen with this code:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

var logoutButton : UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    logoutButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = logoutButton

}
```

The iOS simulator just shows an empty (white) table view. I thought this would be a pretty simple task and have no idea why its not working or where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Update: I have also tried to add navigation buttons to UINavigationController and UIViewController; the code looks like this

```
class ViewController: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let logoutButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = logoutButton
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let logoutButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = logoutButton
}
```

My AppDelegate looks like this:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Nothing works. I cannot get a button to display. I don't want to use storyboards but I'm left with few other options if I can't even get a button to load. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: UITableViewController does not inherit with UInavigationcontroller, see this for ref :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689886/navigation-bar-not-showing-after-adding-navigationcontroller

Comment: Make sure you have a navigation controller.

Comment: First of all Are you using UINavigationController to show ViewController? If not you can't get navigationItem.

Comment: Im not using a UINavigationController. I set this ViewController to the root view of the window in AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the appDelegate. The rootViewController should have been set like:

```
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationViewController(rootViewController: UITableViewController())
```

As opposed to:

```
window?.rootViewController = UITableViewController()
```

I think this is what the comments were trying to point out; thanks!

Answer (score -3):

in this case you are have to push a loginViewController again at a logout time instead you need to popToRootViewControllerAnimated code
use this code on your logout button clickEvnet:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

if you are using swift then use this code

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: This answer is not relevant with the question asked, and has problems. If your app needs authentication, don't navigate through your navigation stack, instead change the navigation stack.